# How do i prevent a form from taking up entire view

Tags: swift, swiftui, vstack

I have a Form and a Button in a VStack, but the form takes up nearly the entire view and the button is forced at the bottom. I am trying to make the button come right after the form, but so far my attempts with padding and spacer have failed. Anyone else know how to prevent a form from taking up the entire view?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the button into the form.

```
  VStack {
    Form {
      Text("blah")
      Button("blubb") { }
    }
  }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:
1 - if you know the frame of your form, you can set the frame for the Form and set infinity height for VStack to fill the entire screen

```swift
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Text("blah")
            }.frame(height: 300)
            Button("blubb") { }
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    }
```

2 - embed the Button in Form and separate it using Section

```swift
VStack {
   Form {
      Text("blah")
      Section {
         Button("blubb") { }
      }
   }
}
```